# how to use formula variable in summarize

Tags: r

I want to write a function which takes a formula as a parameter which is then used in a summarize. To illustrate, what works, I do

```
summarize(mtcars,.by=(cyl),across(disp,~mean(.x)))
```

When I put `~mean(.x)` into a variable, no luck:

```
my_f <- ~mean(.x)
summarize(mtcars,.by=(cyl),across(disp,my_f))
```

R tells me that it cannot find `my_f`.

PS: running R version 4.3.2

Comment: Your code works for me, and the outputs are identical. (R-4.3.2, dplyr_1.1.4.)